# Why have a wrapper constructor when storing a function in a data type?

Tags: haskell

I can never do too many Haskell tutorials.  There is always something to refine and learn.  So, I am working through chapter 10 of [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/code-case-study-parsing-a-binary-data-format.html), and everything makes sense.

*but*

Why do

```
newtype Parse a = Parse { runParse :: ParseState -> Either String (a, ParseState) }

identity :: a -> Parse a
identity a = Parse (\s -> Right (a, s))

getState :: Parse ParseState
getState = Parse (\s -> Right (s, s))

putState :: Parse ()
putState = Parse (\s -> Right ((), s))
```

Why not simply do

```
type Parse a = ParseState -> Either String (a, ParseState)

identity :: a -> Parse a
identity a = \s -> Right (a, s)

getState :: Parse ParseState
getState = \s -> Right (s, s)

putState :: Parse ()
putState = \s -> Right ((), s)
```

In other words, what is the purpose of the wrap and unwrap pattern in here (which I see used in a lot of different places in Haskell)?  We get the same `Parse Whatever` data type, but without the extra indirection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is that Haskell doesn't have arbitrary type lambdas, so when we want to eventually make our `Parse` type an instance of `Monad`, a `newtype` is required.

Comment: Isn't this a case of YAGNI, or at least YAGNIY (You ain't gonna need it yet)?

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realize that was the issue.  So far as YAGNIY goes, the entire book is pretty questionable in how it presents information, but since monads get involved with almost every major construct, leading in that direction makes some sense.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Both monads and applicative functors are used to great effect for parsing. To keep with RWH, chapter 16 uses both styles. Yeah, if you're not gonna support either anyway (RWH ch. 10 apparently doesn't), it's kind of moot. But other examples of this "pattern" (such as State and ErrorT, as OP mentioned in another comment) *are* monads (or monad transformers, for ErrorT), and instances of numerous other type classes as well, so YANI - You *Already* Need It.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like using the notation you're taking issue with is a point of contention. From the comments on that Real World Haskell page:

> I'm trying to go through the monad chapter now (chapter 14), and it
>   looks more and more like the parse example in this chapter is somewhat
>   contrived, in that some concepts it presents don't make sense and lead
>   to what looks like needlessly hard-to-understand and complicated code...

and

> While newtype and record syntax are explained in chapter 6, here (and
>   for the rest of the book) they're not used for "records", just for
>   what looks like a poor man's substitute for encapsulation. I can't
>   really see why. Isn't the module system provided by Haskell enough for
>   this purpose?

In other words, the answer may well be "don't".

Comment: Well, same structure is used with State and ErrorT.  I assume it's used in a lot of other places.  I just don't get why.  I think I may try the rest of that chapter without the constructor.